# Creating a token count by date and co-occurence term proportion by date using quanteda

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, data-wrangling, quanteda

I have a quite massive dataset that contains reviews of utilities services from customers all over the UK, this is a small sample of what the data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame (text  = c("The investors and their supporters shall invest and do something mostly invest",
         " Shall we tell the investors to invest ?",  "Investors shall invest.",
         "Investors may sometimes invest","spend what Investor Do"),
                  date = c("10/12/2022", "10/12/2022", "10/12/2022","11/12/2022","12/12/2022"))
```

What I want is to be able to count the frequency of terms/words/tokens by `date`.

For instance, the word `invest` appears 6 times in total, so for the date 10/12/2022 its word count is 4 I want to be able to use the quanteda library (since it is so powerful) to achieve the count and plot the viz over `date`.

I also want to plot the association or co-occurence of the word investor & invest over date

For instance, we have in this example 5 reviews in those reviews 4/5 times the word invest and investor were present and I'd like to plot that percentage over `date` as well. Is that is possible? What amazing options does the quantada lib has that can perform this task? Will it be possible to also find lets say a min percentage of the 0.25 most frequent words that appear when "invest" appears?

To achieve the first point I started with the following code:

```
df %>% 
  corpus(text_field="text") %>% 
  dfm() %>%
  textstat_frequency(10)
```

which gives:

```
      feature frequency rank docfreq group
1      invest         6    1       5   all
2   investors         4    2       4   all
3       shall         3    3       3   all
4         the         2    4       2   all
5         and         2    4       1   all
6          do         2    4       2   all
7       their         1    7       1   all
8  supporters         1    7       1   all
9   something         1    7       1   all
10         we         1    7       1   all
Warning message:
'dfm.corpus()' is deprecated. Use 'tokens()' first.
```

How would I go about plotting the frequency of this words over the date column? I read in the documentation that one can group but I had have no luck in doing so.

And for the second question I don't know for sure if what function of the quenteda lib to use but I am trying to mirror the  `tm::findAssocs()` fun from the tm library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question:

The dates are put into the `docvars` part of your corpus. This can be used within the `textstat_frequency` with the `group` option.

```
dat <- data.frame (text  = c("The investors and their supporters shall invest and do something mostly invest",
                            " Shall we tell the investors to invest ?",  "Investors shall invest.",
                            "Investors may sometimes invest","spend what Investor Do"),
                  date = c("10/12/2022", "10/12/2022", "10/12/2022","11/12/2022","12/12/2022"))


library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textstats)

dat %>% 
  corpus(text_field="text") %>% 
  tokens() %>%
  dfm() %>% 
  textstat_frequency(groups = date)

      feature frequency rank docfreq      group
1      invest         4    1       3 10/12/2022
2   investors         3    2       3 10/12/2022
3       shall         3    2       3 10/12/2022
4         the         2    4       2 10/12/2022
5         and         2    4       1 10/12/2022
6       their         1    6       1 10/12/2022
7  supporters         1    6       1 10/12/2022
8          do         1    6       1 10/12/2022
9   something         1    6       1 10/12/2022
10     mostly         1    6       1 10/12/2022
11         we         1    6       1 10/12/2022
12       tell         1    6       1 10/12/2022
13         to         1    6       1 10/12/2022
14          ?         1    6       1 10/12/2022
15          .         1    6       1 10/12/2022
16  investors         1    1       1 11/12/2022
17     invest         1    1       1 11/12/2022
18        may         1    1       1 11/12/2022
19  sometimes         1    1       1 11/12/2022
20         do         1    1       1 12/12/2022
21      spend         1    1       1 12/12/2022
22       what         1    1       1 12/12/2022
23   investor         1    1       1 12/12/2022
```

You now have access to the frequency per day.

As for question 2, I think you can use `textstat_simil`. Something like below. It does give some different answers as using `tm::findAssoc`, usually more features. So I'm not completely sure if this is the correct answer. Maybe someone from the quanteda team can confirm or deny this.

```
my_dfm <- dat %>% 
  corpus(text_field="text") %>% 
  tokens() %>%
  dfm()

textstat_simil(my_dfm, 
               my_dfm[, c("investor")], 
               method = "correlation", 
               margin = "features",
               min_simil = 0.7)

textstat_simil object; method = "correlation"
           investor
the               .
investors         .
and               .
their             .
supporters        .
shall             .
invest            .
do                .
something         .
mostly            .
we                .
tell              .
to                .
?                 .
.                 .
may               .
sometimes         .
spend             1
what              1
investor          1
```

You can save the outcome of textstat_simil as a data.frame or list if you want to with `as.data.frame` or `as.list`.

Comment: Thank you so much phiver where did you learn all of this??? thank you so much

Comment: @R_Student, learned by doing text mining projects (at work and home), reading the documentation at [quanteda.io](https://quanteda.io/)